# Parameter expansion with double caret ^^

Tags: regex, bash, parameter-expansion

In the following block of code, how are line# 3 and 4 evaluated?

```bash
for f in "${CT_LIB_DIR}/scripts/build/debug/"*.sh; do
    _f="$(basename "${f}" .sh)"
    _f="${_f#???-}"
    __f="CT_DEBUG_${_f^^}"
done
```

Comment: Next time you can remove the ìf..fi` block (not relevant) or debug yourself by adding `echo "$f -> ${_f} -> ${__f}"`.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```bash
${PARAMETER#PATTERN}
```

Substring removal

This form is to remove the described pattern trying to match it from the beginning of the string. The operator "#" will try to remove the shortest text matching the pattern, while "##" tries to do it with the longest text matching.

```bash
STRING="Hello world"
echo "${STRING#??????}"
>> world
```

---

```bash
${PARAMETER^}
${PARAMETER^^}
${PARAMETER,}
${PARAMETER,,}
```

These expansion operators modify the case of the letters in the expanded text.

The `^` operator modifies the first character to uppercase, the `,` operator to lowercase. When using the double-form (`^^` and `,,`), all characters are converted.

Example:

```bash
var="somewords"
echo ${var^^}
>> SOMEWORDS
```

See [more information on bash parameter expansion](https://bash-hackers.gabe565.com/syntax/pe)

Comment: Just for reference to anyone else reading this, replacing `#` and `##` with `%` and `%%` (respectively) does the same thing, but from the end.

Comment: Also, `~` and `~~` can be used to flip the case (analogous to `^`, `^^`, `,`, `,,`)

Answer (score 1):

The lines 2,3,4 are for constructing a variable name

```
(2)    _f="$(basename "${f}" .sh)"
(3)    _f="${_f#???-}"
(4)    __f="CT_DEBUG_${_f^^}"
```

In line 2 the path is removed and also the .sh at the end.
In line 3 the first 4 characters are removed when the fourth character is a `-`.
In line 4 it is appended to a string and converted to uppercase.
Let's see what happens to a/b/c.sh and ddd-eee.sh

```
       a/b/c.sh       ddd-eee.sh
(2)    c              ddd-eee
(3)    c              eee
(4)    CT_DEBUG_C     CT_DEBUG_EEE
```

Steps 2,3,4 can be replaced by 1 line:

```
__f=$(sed -r 's#(.*/)*(...-)?(.*).sh#CT_DEBUG_\U\3#' <<< "$f")
```

EDIT: First I had `(...-)*`, that would fail with `aaa-bbb-c.sh`: `bbb-` would be removed too!

In this case you don't have the variable `_f` what is used later in the code, so you might want 2 lines:

```
_f=$(sed -r 's#(.*/)*(...-)?(.*).sh#\3#' <<< "$f")
__f="CT_DEBUG_${_f^^}"
```